# Rythm engine ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value

Tags: rythm, classformaterror

We use Rythm engine and sporadically it keeps giving below error. It works fine 90% of the time. We create one instance per thread

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/02/14 11:01:12 | java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 3405691594 in class file C0a10f69e_cfb4_390e_ac5d_bbf66958669e__R_T_C__
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/02/14 11:01:12 |   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/02/14 11:01:12 |   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/02/14 11:01:12 |   at org.rythmengine.internal.compiler.TemplateClassLoader.loadTemplateClass(TemplateClassLoader.java:297)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/02/14 11:01:12 |   at org.rythmengine.internal.compiler.TemplateClassLoader.loadClass(TemplateClassLoader.java:254)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/02/14 11:01:12 |   at org.rythmengine.internal.compiler.TemplateClass.getJavaClass(TemplateClass.java:371)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/02/14 11:01:12 |   at org.rythmengine.internal.compiler.TemplateClass.templateInstance_(TemplateClass.java:387)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/02/14 11:01:12 |   at org.rythmengine.internal.compiler.TemplateClass.asTemplate(TemplateClass.java:413)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/02/14 11:01:12 |   at org.rythmengine.internal.compiler.TemplateClass.asTemplate(TemplateClass.java:419)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/02/14 11:01:12 |   at org.rythmengine.RythmEngine.getTemplate(RythmEngine.java:924)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/02/14 11:01:12 |   at org.rythmengine.RythmEngine.getTemplate(RythmEngine.java:945)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/02/14 11:01:12 |   at org.rythmengine.RythmEngine.render(RythmEngine.java:1019)
```

This is how we create engine

```
public class RythmEngineUtil {

    /**

 * clear the rythm Pre compiled data
 */
static{
    try {
        File dir = new File("./", "__rythm");
        if(!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdir();
        }else{
            deleteDirAndChildren(dir);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static void deleteDirAndChildren(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Initilize Rythm Engine
 */
private static ThreadLocal<RythmEngine> rythmEngine = new ThreadLocal<RythmEngine>() {
    protected RythmEngine initialValue() {

        Map<String, Object> conf = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        conf.put("rythm.codegen.compact", false);
        conf.put("engine.precompile_mode", true);
        conf.put("engine.load_precompiled", true);
        conf.put("home.template","xyz/some");
        conf.put("home.precompiled.dir", new File("./", "__rythm"));
        RythmEngine engine = new RythmEngine(conf);

        System.out.println("Got new RythmEngine -" + engine.getId());

        return engine;
    }

};


public static RythmEngine getEngine() {
    return rythmEngine.get();
}

private RythmEngineUtil() {
}

private static RythmEngineUtil _instance = new RythmEngineUtil();

public static RythmEngineUtil getInstance() {
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

And then use it like

RythmEngineUtil.getEngine()

Comment: Why do you create Multiple engines? each engine has its own class loader, if engine A's compiled template bytecode (in TEMP_DIR) get loaded by engine B, it might cause the issue

Comment: @green We are multi-threaded system. Multiple threads needs to do various jobs with engine. As per documentation, rythm engine is not thread safe. We do not want to put java synchronized for each request as it will slowdown our processing. That is why we created multiple engine per thread. It is used as ThreadLocal variable.

Comment: that's not correct. rythm engine is thread safe. Even if you want to add `synchronous` to every request is way faster than your current solution

Comment: @green  https://github.com/rythmengine/rythmengine/issues/287 stats that it is not thread safe as of 1.x version which we use.